# Spring Security not allowing POST

Tags: java, maven, spring-security, jwt, amazon-cognito

I have a requirement to lock down an existing REST API application containing many endpoints. The application receives a cognito token from the client via the Authorization header as a Bearer token.  That token is verified by AWS cognito against this url in application.properties:

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=https://cognito-idp.${aws.cognito.region}.amazonaws.com/${aws.user.pools.id}
```

I've imported the following jars to support this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And here is the SecurityConfiguration class

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class JWTSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
          .authorizeRequests(authz -> authz
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated())
          .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt());
    }
}
```

It seems to work fine for GET, but the POST calls fail with a 403 Forbidden.  I have it open to everything that is authenticated for now until I can get it working. I'm thinking the answer lies somewhere in the SecurityConfiguration configure method code.

In case it's relevant to this, I also had to add "Authorization" to the "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" header to an existing old school Filter w doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp) used by the application like this (pasted in all the headers in case it's helpful):

```
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should configure CORS for anything that can alter resources (POST, PUT, DELETE):

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Enable and configure CORS
        http.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource());
        ...
        return http.build();
    }

    private CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        // Very permissive CORS config...
        final var configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));

        // Limited to API routes (neither actuator nor Swagger-UI)
        final var source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/greet/**", configuration);

        return source;
    }
```

Side note, do not extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` which is deprecated. Instead, provide your application context with a `SecurityFilterChain` @Bean as done in the sample above.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I overlooked the fact that the front end was not sending the token in the Authorization header on POST, but is for GET.  But that still was not the issue. Needed to add .csrf().disable(); at the end of the SecurityConfig code below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class JWTSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
        .authorizeRequests(authz -> authz
          .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**").authenticated()
          .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").authenticated()
          .anyRequest().permitAll())//Everything else is allowed without auth
        .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt())
        .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```